# Rule governing sequence of fields in a YAML

Tags: yaml

Checking the validity of a YAML using https://onlineyamltools.com/convert-yaml-to-json

The below YAML is correct

```
# Valid yaml (field "name" placed at LAST position)
match:
- uri:
    prefix: "/mysvc1/"
route:
- destination:
    host: myservice1
    port:
        number: 80
name: "svc1-routes"
```

However, if I move the field `name` to first position, the YAML becomes invalid. What is the reason?

```
# Invalid yaml (field "name" placed at FIRST position)
match:
name: "svc1-routes" # <---- ERROR ----
- uri:
    prefix: "/mysvc1/"
route:
- destination:
    host: myservice1
    port:
        number: 80
```

The error message:

```
Error: YAMLException: end of the stream or a document separator is expected at line 4, column 1:
    - uri:
    ^
```

Comment: `name` is a field of the block which contains `match`, so name and match are siblings if you add `name` above `match`, it will work, because match is object and has properties uri and route.

Comment: `name: "svc1-routes"
match:
- uri:
    prefix: "/mysvc1/"
route:
- destination:
    host: myservice1
    port:
        number: 80`

Comment: Thanks. I misread the indentation and though `uri`, `route` and `name` are subfields on the parent `match` field. They are actually siblings. The error I made was `- uri:` which I thought was a field. It is actually just an item in of the field `match` of type list. Noiw I understand why placing the `name` field in the 2nd example breaks the structure of the `match` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrary to your comment, `name` and `match` are on the same level because they share the same indentation. `name` is in no way nested in `match` (nor is `route`).

The list items, however, *are* nested in `match` since YAML understands the `-` as parts of the indentation, hence the list items are considered more indented than `match` and are thus nested in it.

Concerning your error:

```yaml
name: "svc1-routes"
- uri:
```

In this part, the mapping key `name` is assigned the scalar value `svc1-routes`. Each mapping key may only have one value. On the next line, a sequence starts which is on a deeper indentation level (as explained above) but YAML can't put it anywhere because the key `name` already has a value. This is why it issues an error.

You can freely switch the mapping keys together with their nested values, e.g.:

```yaml
route:
- destination:
    host: myservice1
    port:
        number: 80
name: "svc1-routes"
match:
- uri:
    prefix: "/mysvc1/"
```

This will load to the same structure as per YAML spec.

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense. Thanks. BTW, kudos for the speed. You actually answered to a misleading comment I had left in the initial post for about 10 minutes.

Comment: Well you know how it is: Ask a question on the internet and get little reaction for three hours, but make a wrong statement and someone will instantly come and correct you :)